# Button click action FIND / REPLACE

Tags: c#, winforms

I can't seem to get my button to work. This is the first time i've tried to make an application. I just need a simple find / replace. I found some code on the internet and can't seem to get it to work.

http://pastebin.com/9v6TEFMs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Deneuralyzer : Form
    {
        public Deneuralyzer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using System;
            using System.IO;
            using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


                    string filePath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\location\to\application\textfile.txt";
                    string searchText = "Count,2,";
                    string replaceText = "Count,200,";
                    ReplaceInFile(filePath, searchText, replaceText);


                    static public void ReplaceInFile(string filePath, string searchText, string replaceText)
                    {

                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
                        string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        reader.Close();

                        content = Regex.Replace(content, searchText, replaceText);

                        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath);
                        writer.Write(content);
                        writer.Close();
                    }

        }

    }
}
```

also, does something specific need to be done, so that the application can edit the file? because doing it by hand I must change the file permissions and ownership.

errors out when i run the test

> Error    3   Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected   C:\Users\Jack\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs  59  1   WindowsFormsApplication1
>
> Error    4   Syntax error, '(' expected  C:\Users\Jack\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs  27  19  WindowsFormsApplication1
>
> Error    6   Syntax error, '(' expected  C:\Users\Jack\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs  28  19  WindowsFormsApplication1
>
> Error    8   Syntax error, '(' expected  C:\Users\Jack\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs  29  19  WindowsFormsApplication1
>
> Error    2   Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct    C:\Users\Jack\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs  54  17  WindowsFormsApplication1
>
> Error    1   } expected  C:\Users\Jack\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs  35  70  WindowsFormsApplication1
>
> Error    5   ) expected  C:\Users\Jack\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs  27  25  WindowsFormsApplication1
>
> Error    7   ) expected  C:\Users\Jack\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs  28  28  WindowsFormsApplication1
>
> Error    9   ) expected  C:\Users\Jack\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs  29  49  WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: Please post your code here, not on pastebin. Not everyone can view pastebin from work - also it makes reading your question easier on all

Comment: done. just discovered CTRL+K, i used to add four spaces to each line, time consuming. :\ :)

Comment: Only thing I can think of is UAC on windows 7 may prevent your app from writing to the area.. What if the file was somewhere more sensible? The code looks reasonable on face value - of course, if you look for " my name" and it finds "My name" it wont replace it..  Otherwise the code should work - you can test it with another string..  You could also use file.ReadAllText to read the file - but Im wondering if you need to add some regex options such as RegexOptions.MultiLine

Comment: the button itself is not working. i posted the error codes above.

Comment: Ah - you see, you didnt post your errors originally - it makes it a lot more of a guessing game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up on how to structure a class, or perhaps a [C# tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436%28VS.71%29.aspx). Normally you have the following order of elements in a class

```
// using statements, other components you use in your class
using System;
// namespace name (a group so to speak)
namespace NamespaceName {

    // class, this gets nested under a namespace
    public class MyClass {

        // private variables
        private int myVariable;

        // constructors
        public MyClass() {
            // this is where you create the instance, set variables and stuff
            myVariable = 314;
        }

        // methods
        public void DoSomething() {
            ++myVariable;
        }

        private void anotherMethod() { }
    }
}
```

Now, when the compiler tries to parse your codefile, since it's not structured in this manner, it complains

When you try to build the project the Error list window pops up with the errors you specified. You can double click each of these items and address them. What you can do is after each fix try to compile again, since some errors might be "follow up errors", i.e. errors which are fixed due to the first error being fixed.

In your case you have a method in the button click method. This is not allowed for a C# class, so you need to close the buttonClick method scope (the `{ }` brackets that is) and move the using statements to the top of the cs file.

A tip is to indent your code since well formatted code is easier to read. Visual Studio makes this easy, you can click the Edit menu, choose Advanced and click Format Document (remember the shortcut Ctrl-k Ctrl-d). It can also help spot some errors, such as unmatched brackets.

---

Edit: Another tip btw is the Right click - Organize usings - Remove and sort option, to clear the cludder in the using statements in the beginning of the file. In many cases you don't need half of the ones which are included by default when Visual Studio creates a file. Later, if you find that you have a unrecognized class, press Ctrl + . ("ctrl dot") and you get the option to include the using statement needed for that class.